# Is there a formula for $\int_0^1 x\uparrow\uparrow n dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

$$\int_0^1  x\uparrow\uparrow n dx$$
I was working on an answer to this question on [integrating $x^{x^x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3601774/integrating-xxx/4243649#4243649) and I was thinking is there a particular formula/rule/pattern in integration if $x\uparrow\uparrow n$ ($x$ to the power of $x \ n$ times) from $0$ to $1$. Integrating $x^x$ we use the Taylor series to arrive a

$$\int_0^1 x^xdx=\int_0^1 e^{x\ln(x)}dx =\int_0^1 \sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{x^n\ln^n(x)}{n!}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^n}=0.78343\ldots
$$
similarly integrating $x^{x^x}$ the taylor series would be $$x^{x^x}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\ln^n(x)}{n!}x^{x^n}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\ln^n(x)}{n!}\Bigg(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k\ln^k(x)}{k!}\Bigg)^n$$
and integrating $x\uparrow\uparrow 3$ the series would be

$$x^{x^{x^x}}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\ln^n(x)}{n!}x^{x^{x^n}}=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\ln^n(x)}{n!}\Bigg(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\ln^k(x)}{k!}x^{x^k}\Bigg)^n=
\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{\ln^n(x)}{n!}\Bigg(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\ln^k(x)}{k!}\Big(\sum^\infty_{m=0}\frac{x^m\ln^m(x)}{m!}\Big)^k\Bigg)^n
$$

So is there a solution to the integral?
$$\int_0^1  x\uparrow\uparrow n dx$$
Can it be simplified? Can one find series solutions for all $n$? What if $n\not\in \mathbb{N}$?

I have been interested in this function for quite a long time so thank you for your time

Comment: What is the accepted definition for fractional tetration? Also possible duplicate of [How to integrate $\int\underbrace{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^x}}}}_ndx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427816/how-to-integrate-int-underbracexx-cdot-cdotx-ndx/4173761#4173761)

Comment: I would suggest visiting this link from MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259278/an-explicit-series-representation-for-the-analytic-tetration-with-complex-height

Comment: @ArjunVyavaharkar How could you integrate fractional tetration as this would be fascinating for users like us? Thanks.

Comment: @hwood Thanks for the bounty. Wouldn’t others also deserve it and the accept?

Answer (score 4):

There is no generally accepted definition for $^nx$ when $n\not\in\mathbb{N}$. So I am not going to talk about it.

From [Wolfram Alpha](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html) we have that,

$\textstyle\displaystyle{^nx=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(k+1)^k}{(k+1)!}\ln^k(x)+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}a_{n,k}\ln^k(x)}$

Where,

$$\textstyle\displaystyle{
a_{n,k} =
\begin{cases}
  1,  & k = 0 \\
  \frac{1}{n!},  & n = 1 \\
  \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{n}ja_{n,k-j}a_{n-1,k-1},  & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}}
$$

So, $\textstyle\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{1}{^nx}dx}$

$=\textstyle\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{1}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(k+1)^k}{(k+1)!}\ln^k(x)+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}a_{n,k}\ln^k(x)\right)dx}$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(k+1)^k}{(k+1)!}\int_{0}^{1}\ln^k(x)dx+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}a_{n,k}\int_{0}^{1}\ln^k(x)dx}$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{k^{k-2}}{k!}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n,k}}{k+1}}$

*If you want want an explicit formula for $a_{n,k}$ Then forgive me I don't know. I don't even know how is the series representation of $^nx$ derived. So yeah*

Answer (score 3):

I do not have a solution, but I do have an algorithm for finding such solutions using simple [Taylor Series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of an $n\in\Bbb N$ height power tower at $x=1$. These power towers usually have rational coefficients. If you do the Taylor series about another point, then you get a polynomial of natural logarithms. Here are a few examples.

> [$$\int x^x dx$$
> using the Lehmer-Comtet constants](https://oeis.org/A005727).

> [$$\int x^{x^x}dx$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4152861/inverse-function-of-xxx/4190831#4190831)
> using [A179230 and the Exponential Generating function of $$(x+1)^{(x+1)^{x+1}}$$](https://oeis.org/A179230)

> [$$\int x^{x^{x^x}}dx$$](http://oeis.org/A179405)

> [$n=5$](http://oeis.org/A179505)

> [$n=6$](http://oeis.org/A211205)

> [$n=7$](http://oeis.org/A277538)

> [$n=8$](http://oeis.org/A277539)

> [$n=9$](http://oeis.org/A277540)

> [$n=10$](http://oeis.org/A277541)

> [$n\ge 11?$](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C2%2C9%2C56&sort=&language=&go=Search)

[Inverse of $n=\infty$ case](http://oeis.org/search?q=A008405&sort=&language=english&go=Search)

Note that $x^\frac{1}{x}$ is the inverse of $x\uparrow\uparrow\infty=\lim_{n\to\infty} \,n\text{ times}\big\{x^{x^{x^…}}$ for the [Infinite Power Tower convergence interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890319/convergence-of-tetration-sequence) and not the [analytic continuation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration).

Here is the general solution and one assuming the interval of convergence works:
$$\int x\uparrow\uparrow n dx =\int\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\left[\frac{d^k}{dx^k} (x\uparrow\uparrow n)\right]_{x=1}\ (x-1)^k}{k!} dx= \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\left[\frac{d^{k-1}}{dx^{k-1}} (x\uparrow\uparrow n)\right]_{x=1}\ (x-1)^k}{k!}\mathop=^\text{definite integral}_\text{from 0 to 1} -\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\left[\frac{d^{k-1}}{dx^{k-1}} (x\uparrow\uparrow n)\right]_{x=1}\ (-1)^k}{k!} $$

> If you know the convergence intervals, I would love to really know so that we could apply the same to similar problems.

I suggest using @Arjun’s suggestion for the [non-natural number tetration](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259278/an-explicit-series-representation-for-the-analytic-tetration-with-complex-height). Please correct me and give me feedback!

Answer (score 3):

I cannot give an answer as detailed as @Tyma Gaidash's, but what I *can* give you is an approximation.

The answer to the integral, $$y(x)=\int_0^1 {}^x t\; \textrm{d}t$$ is approximately $$\dfrac{y_\textrm{sup}(x)+y_\textrm{inf}(x)}{2}+\dfrac{y_\textrm{sup}(x)-y_\textrm{inf}(x)}{2} \cos(\pi x)$$ where $y_\textrm{sup}$ and $y_\textrm{inf}$ are both exponential functions. The exact details are in the following graph, which has an $R^2$ of ~$0.9977$:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e56wdxumxv